# Identify the line with word repeated consecutively in Bash

Tags: regex, string, bash

Suppose I have the following file:

```
one two three
two three four
three four four
three four five
```

How do I determine in which line there was a consecutively repeating word? I'm trying to get an output that looks like this:

```
3:four:three four four
```

with first the line number, then the word, and then the line in which the word appears.

This is what I have so far:

```
while read line
do
   echo $line > file
   sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n/g' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -1
done < $1
```

I'm not sure how to continue. The output is currently this:

```
1 two
1 two
2 four
1 three
```

I was thinking of passing the output of

> `head -1`

to a custom made script which takes the frequency and word as arguments, but there must be a simpler way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==$(i+1)){print NR,$i,$0 }}' OFS=':' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==$(i+1)){print NR,$i,$0 }}' OFS=':' file
3:four:three four four
```

#### Explanation:

- We iterate over each elements on the line
- We compare each element to the next element
- If we find them identical, we print the line number, element and the entire line delimited by a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Except for printing the line numbers, this does it:

```
sed -n -r '/\b([^ ]+) \1\b/s/^.*\b([^ ]+) \1\b/\1:&/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

If a Perl solution is ok, then this might help:

```
perl -lne '/\b(\w+) \1\b/ && print join ":",$.,$1,$_;' file
```

Comment: wow @Guru can you please explain the the part after `print join` what do `$` represent ?

Comment: @aelor They are `perl` special variables. `$.` holds the line number, `$1` has the captured back-reference (in this case the word) and `$_` holds the entire line. Since line is not delimited by a `:`, `join` helps print everything delimited by a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
cat -n stack | sed -n -r '/\b([^ ]+) \1\b/s/^.*\b([^ ]+) \1\b/\1:&/p' | sed 's/     / /' | awk '{ i = $1; $1 = $2":"; $2 = i; print; }'
```

use cat -n to number the lines then use Barmar's sed command.  After that you get remove all the extra spaces, switch the values of column 1 and 2 and print it out.  As close as I could get it:

```
 3: four: three four four
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a BASH loop with regex matching.

```
n=1
while read -a line; do
    for i in ${line[@]}; do
        if [[ ${line[@]} =~ ($i).*($i) ]]; then
            echo "${n}:${i}:${line[@]}"
            break
        fi
    done
    ((n++))
done < $1
```